# Infinite Spinning Wheel

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this code for a VBA macro in the Normal>Module section of the VBA editor named "CntCntrls" that does the following:

- allows me to add rich text content control
- allows me to add a tag/title to the rich text content control
- allows me to edit an existing tag/title to a rich text content control
- allows me to delete any rich text content control that does not have "Me" as the tag. This will also delete the page of the affected rich text content control so that there isn't excess space from the deleted rich text content controls

The problem I'm having is that I'm getting a spinning wheel that loads infinitely but never actually runs the macro despite the document being only 10 pages that I'm using for testing. Is there something you guys can pick up on that may be potentially causing this issue?

Some potentially useful specs:

- MacOs Monterey 12.6.8 on 2021 M1 Macbook pro
- Office Home & Business 2021 License

This is the code that I have:

```vb
    Sub A_A_AddRichTextControl()
    Dim rngSelection As Range
    
    Set rngSelection = Selection.Range
    ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add Type:=wdContentControlRichText, Range:=rngSelection
    End Sub


    Sub A_B_EditTagAndTitleOfRichTextControl()
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Dim newTag As String
    
    If Selection.Range.ContentControls.Count = 1 Then
        Set cc = Selection.Range.ContentControls(1)
        
        ' Prompt for new tag
        newTag = InputBox("Enter new tag for the rich text content control:", "New Tag")
        
        ' Set new tag and title
        If newTag <> "" Then
            cc.tag = newTag
            cc.Title = newTag ' Set title equal to the tag
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Select a single rich text content control to edit tag and title.", vbExclamation
    End If
    End Sub


    Sub A_C_EditContentControlTagAndTitle()
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Dim newTag As String
    
    ' Check if the selection contains a content control
    If Selection.Range.ContentControls.Count > 0 Then
        ' Store a reference to the first content control in the selection
        Set cc = Selection.Range.ContentControls(1)
        
        ' Prompt the user for new tag and title values
        newTag = InputBox("Enter the content control property tag:", "Edit Tag", cc.tag)
        
        ' Update the tag and title
        cc.tag = newTag
        cc.Title = newTag
        
        ' Optional: Refresh the content control to apply changes
        cc.LockContentControl = True
        cc.LockContentControl = False
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select a content control before running this macro.", vbExclamation
    End If
    End Sub


    Sub B_A_RemoveRT_ExceptMe()

    Dim oCC As ContentControl
    Dim arrTagParts() As String
    Dim lngIndex As Long
    Dim bDelete As Boolean
    Dim oPage As Range

    For Each oCC In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        bDelete = True
        If oCC.Type = 0 Then 'wdContentControlText
            arrTagParts = Split(oCC.tag, " ")
            For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(arrTagParts)
                If arrTagParts(lngIndex) = "Me" Then
                    bDelete = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next lngIndex
            If bDelete Then
                ' Get the page range of the content control
                Set oPage = oCC.Range.GoTo(wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, oCC.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber))
                ' Delete the content control
                oCC.Delete True
                ' Delete the entire page
                oPage.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next oCC
    lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
    End Sub
```

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/51733-ms-word-macro-infinite-spinning-wheel-thanks.html  For cross-posting etiquette please see https://excelguru.ca/a-message-to-forum-cross-posters/

Comment: @TimothyRylatt So sorry about this! Never even considered the points made in that article. Thanks for educating me on this so that moving forward, I do it in the correct manner

I do apologize to anyone I've affected with how I've posted this issue I'm having. Please be patient with me as forum etiquette is something I'm very new to

I'll be better moving forward

I'm going to post this same reply on StackOverflow as well so that I can apologize to that user base as well

Again, my sincere apologies!

Comment: FWIW I ran your code on a few quite simple example docs on an M1 Mac and did not encounter the spinning ball. i.e. it's not obviously a Mac-only issue. Personally, I would probably start with a very simple document, check that the problem occurred, then step through the code in the debugger. If a simple document doesn't generate the problem, I'd try to identify what was different about the "failing" document.